# how do I install Firebird 2.1 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: database

When updating form ubuntu 12 to 13 my firebird 2.1 was uninstalled. Now, when I try to install it, it seems that the package is obsolete.

```
root@ricardo-pc:/# apt-get install firebird2.1-classic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package firebird2.1-classic is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'firebird2.1-classic' has no installation candidate
```

How can I install it?

Answer (score 1):

First download the package [listd + +5](http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-3.3/libstdc++5_3.3.6-25_i386.deb).  Once the download is done, go to the folder where you saved the package probably the Downloads folder, and click with the right mouse button.  Select Open with Ubuntu Software Center.  Once software center opens, click on the install button

[image]
[image]

Download [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-2-5-2-upd1/), then just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, go to the folder where you saved the file, probably the Downloads folder, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo Tar-xzf FirebirdSS *. Tar.gz
Cd FirebirdSS *
sudo . / Install.sh
```

When it ask you to enter the password for the SYSDBA user, enter the default password, which is: masterkey

<sup>Source:vivaolinux</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Also is recommended to use Firebird 2.5 (current stable)

> Version series 2.5.x is the last one released by the project and thus
>   it has the highest priority in terms of the bug fixing, with a
>   maintenance cycle of two point releases per year.

http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/server/

Firebird 2.1 is in bug fixing mode (old stable)

Answer (score -1):

My problem **Solved**, try this.

http://www.itlampung.com/2016/05/solved-install-firebird-21-di-server-linux-ubuntu.html